# Firebase authOnStateChange: How to get current user once and unsubscribe if one doesn't exist

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I'm having issues with persisted user.

Obviously `auth.currentUser` will be null before the SDK is init, so I'm using `authStateChanged`.

If user isn't signed in, I want to redirect them to a login page, so I subscribe to auth state, just to check if we have a user, this should be done in the main app component to make sure no user can access anything without an `auth`.

Then the signup page. Since there's a listener for stateChange, as soon as a user is logged in, that listener fires off in the app-component, and starts doing things that are not intended, while we still want to do other things on the signup page.

Is there some way that is documented, to work with Firebase auth.currentUser, to subscribe to that, and get the user from there, just once and a null if there's no user.

Comment: The answer doesn't address your question?

Answer (score 1):

A recommended approach is to only set the status of the user based on the `onAuthStateChange`, resolved and user exists or not then notify your main process of status changes.

or

as documented https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Returns
non-null function() The unsubscribe function for the observer.

which means you can do:

```
const unsub = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
   // User is signed in.
  }
});
```

then whenever you want to unsubscribe :

```
unsub()
```